# creating bug in bugzilla using java

Tags: bugzilla

I am trying to connect bugzilla using java code.I have used the sample shown in this web site http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/208362-bugzilla-webservice-api/. Using the method User.login it is returning {id=1} for the login credentials.But while creating the bug it is showing "Exception in thread "main" org.apache.xmlrpc.XmlRpcException: Login Required " exception.Can any one help me out how to create bugs and get the bugs from bugzilla.

Thanks,
Hima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this library:

[J2Bugzilla : The Java Bugzilla API](http://code.google.com/p/j2bugzilla/)